# Released object crashes app

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management, boost, objective-c++

I am using objective-C++ (+Boost) for iPhone development.

I am in a rather tight loop and need to allocate and release a certain object.

The code is something like this.

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    opt = [[FObj alloc] init];
    //do stuff with opt
    [opt release];
}
```

The FObj object is something like

```
@interface FObj
  MyCPPObj  * cppobj;
@end
```

In the implementation of FObj there is a dealloc method:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
  delete cppobj; //previously allocated with 'new'
  [super dealloc];
}
```

I am afraid that if i don't release then the 'MyCPPObj's will just pile up. But releasing makes the app crash after the first loop. What am I doing wrong?

Or perhaps should I make cppobj and boost::shared_ptr?

(do boost shared pointers automatically release their objects when an objective-C++ object is deleted?)

Comment: Run your app in the debugger and see what it tells you about the crash. You may also want to run your app in Instruments using the Zombies template, in case you're over-releasing the Cocoa object somehow.

Comment: I would love to run it in the debugger, but for some reason (perhaps because of Boost and other huge libraries) the debugger crashes.

Comment: Can you also show us where/how you use `new`? (By the way, I didn't have problems using boost libraries and debugging in Xcode.)

Comment: Is your @interface really declared like that? Rather than like @interface FObj : NSObject { MyCPPObj* cppobj; } @end

Without the curly braces around the cppobj, you're declaring a global variable not an instance variable, and without subclassing NSObject (or a subclass), -release isn't going to work, since it's implemented as a method on NSObject.

Comment: I think we need to see what you're doing with your FObj to determine what's causing the crash

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you show, or with the approach in general. However, no one is able to give you more specific advice without seeing more code. Clearly something is wrong, but it's not in what you've shown us.

Comment: I think Boaz Stuller may be right. If you want an answer to your question, please confirm that the FObj declaration is as you posted it or post the full one.

Comment: What does the declaration of opt look like?  Does it have setter/getter?

Comment: Boaz is right. You haven't told the compiler that FObj performs the `-release` selector.